# NavigationController cut the shadow after push and pop?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

NavigationController has an issue when I add a custom view to navigationBar and this View has a shadow, the shadow cut when push and pop again?

### 1:- ViewController A before push

[image]

### 2:- ViewController B after push

[image]

### 3:- ViewController A after pop

[image]

It's a very simple class just contain this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let view : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 40))

    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 20.0
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    view.clipsToBounds = false
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on some quick inspection...

The `.navigationBar` has a **"contentView"**.

On initial appearance, that contentView has `.clipsToBounds` set to `false`.

Once you push a VC onto the stack, that contentView's `.clipsToBounds` property becomes `true`.

That's why you can see shadow initially.

I think you'll need to find another way to get that appearance... you ***could*** try subclassing, but Apple's doc explicitly state:

> It is permissible to customize the appearance of the navigation bar using the methods and properties of the UINavigationBar class but you must never change its frame, bounds, or alpha values or modify its view hierarchy directly.